# How to initialize LDA with a set of seed words using gensim package

Tags: python, gensim

I have read several papers in which they actually initialize parameteres using a seed set of words for LDA. does anyone know how is this possible in gensim package?

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of completeness, copy&paste from the [gensim mailing list reply](http://groups.google.com/group/gensim/browse_thread/thread/f6fca5b4af28b62e):

> Seeding with existing documents was a part of gensim some versions 
>   back, in the code that was directly ported from LDA-C. It was meant to 
>   improve convergence (although the final, converged result was the 
>   same).
>
> In recent versions, that code was replaced by a more efficient 
>   algorithm which doesn't use seeding anymore. It is an online (mini-batch) 
>   algorithm, so you could say it does "seeding" automatically, in a more 
>   principled manner.

Comment: Can't you still just put a prior on your topics using eta?